# Carbon fork torque

Tags: fork, carbon

I notice that my fork is squeezed together when I tighten the quick release mechanism. Is it possible then to over torque the quick release and squeeze the fork too close together?

Comment: Please post a picture.  The wheel should stop the fork from moving much.  If there is a lot of play something is wrong.

Comment: There's not a lot of play. But the fork does visibly move a few mm when tightening the quick release.

Comment: Sounds like you lost a spacer while adjusting your cones. If you don't like the gap just stick an appropriate spacer/s in between your cone and lock nut. You could even use a washer if you can't find anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're standing on it, probably not, especially if its an [external/exposed cam style quick release](http://sheldonbrown.com/skewers.html)

I'm assuming what you're seeing is just the legs coming in a little bit as the spacing is slightly wider than 100mm. As long as it's just a couple of mm, I woudn't worry about it.

Comment: It is quite normal for a fork, any fork to be 1 or 2mm wider than the required 100mm. When the QR release closes the elasticity of the fork takes it up. Anyway the fork flexes more than that during a ride.

Comment: I would measure both the fork and the hub to check if one of them is too much out of spec.

Comment: This is actually the norm for both forks AND frames.